# Choosing Rights Host For Dependency Make

Tags: dependencies

I am working on on creating builds for windows, mac, and Unix. I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 but on a windows OS. I figured  out host-platform-triplets for windows and mac and generated prefixes for them but not sure how to determine the best Unix prefix. I was hoping to run this in a unix container out in gcp as a test harness. Any recommendations or guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following triplets are currently supported by Bitcoin Core's "depends" build system, assuming that's what you're talking about (and even if not, these are fairly standard). From https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/depends/README.md:

- `i686-pc-linux-gnu` for Linux 32 bit
- `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` for x86 Linux
- `x86_64-w64-mingw32` for Win64
- `x86_64-apple-darwin18` for macOS
- `arm-linux-gnueabihf` for Linux ARM 32 bit
- `aarch64-linux-gnu` for Linux ARM 64 bit
- `powerpc64-linux-gnu` for Linux POWER 64-bit (big endian)
- `powerpc64le-linux-gnu` for Linux POWER 64-bit (little endian)
- `riscv32-linux-gnu` for Linux RISC-V 32 bit
- `riscv64-linux-gnu` for Linux RISC-V 64 bit
- `s390x-linux-gnu` for Linux S390X

Added in master (which will become release version 22.0):

- `armv7a-linux-android` for Android ARM 32 bit
- `aarch64-linux-android` for Android ARM 64 bit
- `i686-linux-android` for Android x86 32 bit
- `x86_64-linux-android` for Android x86 64 bit

`x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` would be the most common one (targetting 64-bit x86 systems).

Comment: That's awesome thank out ill try x86_64-pc-linux-gnu. Just need an output from the make -install that I can plave on an ubuntu 18.04 OS and run on a vm in GCP

Comment: Weird I ran the command for make and got this error, /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
funcs.mk:242:. I havent changed this file and have used it to make WIndows and Mac depend prefixes